# JSP not rendering list data

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, controller, empty-list

I have a simple Spring MVC application running. I can pass a string value from controller to jsp - working fine.

When the controller is asked to pass list data, it fails to render in the jsp view. I have tested the data on the controller side to be sure it is not empty before passing to the jsp.

Code extracts below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView printWelcome(){   

    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>();
    listData.add("Hello");
    listData.add("World");


    for(int i =0; i< listData.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(listData.get(i));
    }

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("list");
    modelAndView.addObject("lists", listData);

    return modelAndView;                
}



<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>


    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${listData}">
            <li>${listValue}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>


</body>
```

EDIT:

The problem was my spring conf. (I think - as I am still new to this.)

The controller was returning a ModelAndView object, when in fact it should only return the string View name. Also the working controller has a constructor with parameter arg ModelView, in which the list data needs to be appended to.`

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap map){

    List<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>();
    listData.add("Hello");
    listData.add("World");

    map.addAttribute("lists", listData);
    //return list;
    return "list";

}
```

Comment: do you have `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` at the top of the jsp?

Comment: Yes I have added this and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using as below. You should be using the key with which you stored in the model. It behaves like a HashMap.

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">
      <li>${listValue}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello minion, this code will produce the same result, namely a single list bullet point is rendered with nothing after it!

Comment: Can you show me what is it printing? What do you mean by, this code will show the same result? Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it. I mean that a single dot for the first list item is printed and after this, nothing. I have also updated the jsp with <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> although this causes no bullet point to be output..

Comment: Can you show me the example where string value worked when passed from controller. There is something missing, which i cannot find out with the info given. Also post you servlet config and are you using maven or something to build?

Comment: Hi Minion, I've managed to get it working my returning to the working example. I've added this to the original post.

Comment: So is it working? I could not see the example in original post.

Comment: It is working. I've just now added the example. I think this problem - or solution rather - may be specific to spring 4 although I cannot be sure. Perhaps you could enlighten me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72069/discussion-between-minion-and-jnanathan).

Comment: Well, i think it should not be a problem sending a MAV or String. Iterating through correct collection name is the key there. Accept my answer if it had helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line to the top :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Then you can use `<c:` as a taglib prefix.